# How to remove a character from a Linux terminal in C

Tags: c, linux, terminal

How can I remove a character on the terminal before the cursor in Linux? In the past I used something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define KEY_BACKSPACE 127

int main(){
    printf("%s", "abc"); // add something so we can see if delete works
    char * buf = malloc(3*sizeof(char));
    *(buf+0)=KEY_BACKSPACE;
    *(buf+1)=' ';
    *(buf+2)=KEY_BACKSPACE;
    write(1,buf,3);
    free(buf);
}
```

This is only a small example demonstrating this technique. In the original program I disabled canonical mode and handled every keystroke myself. That's why I needed to remove characters.

Writing backspace, space, backspace worked fine in my original program. Now when I run same program after a few years, it didn't remove anything. What changed? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Using the 'delete' key code to do a backspace is weird; you'd need to use backspace `'\b'` under most systems.  You also need to `fflush(stdout)` to get the `abc` string onto the screen before the `write()` overwrites part of it.  Or use `write()` to print the `abc` string too.

Comment: I freed buffer and used *write* instead if *printf*. That was not the problem I tried to demonstrate. As comment points out, problem is in using character 127. (I don't know why this ever worked.) Btw thanks for fast comment.

Comment: A possible explanation would be that you were using a terminal emulator (or terminal) that went out of its way to interpret a raw 127 coming its way, and that today's crop of terminal emulators no longer do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488591/how-to-remove-character-from-linux-terminal-in-c#comment75971351_44488591), you need to use backspace instead of `'\177'` (or `'\x7F'`) to move backwards. You also have to worry about buffering of standard I/O.  It's often best not to use a mixture of standard I/O and file descriptor I/O on the same stream — standard output in this example.  Use one or the other, but not both.

This works:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff1[] = "abc";
    char buff2[] = "\b \b";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff1, sizeof(buff1) - 1);
    sleep(2);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff2, sizeof(buff2) - 1);
    sleep(2);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

It shows first (for 2 seconds):

```
abc
```

then (for another 2 seconds):

```
ab
```

then it exits.  The cursor is after `c` at first, then after `b`.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Jonathan Leffler in the comment, your code needs two modifications:

- The rubout character understood by the typical terminal (emulator) is `'\b'` (or 8), not 127.
- `printf()` is line-buffered by default when writing to a TTY. This means that you need to call `fflush(stdout)` between calls to `printf()` and `write()`. Without flushing `abc` will only be printed at program exit, so the deletion sequence will be emitted *before* the contents it is supposed to delete, which renders it inoperative.